# BigQuery loading batch folders error

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load group of folders files in one time with when 
i set 
sourceURI =  'gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/app/reports/app_network_analytics_report/201409011*'

all the folders that i'm want to load start with 20140911

but i get the error:

ERROR: Invalid path: gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/apn/reports/appnexus_network_analytics_report/20140901191111_3bab8ec0_092a_43de_a157_db35d1555ea0/

20140901191111_3bab8ec0_092a_43de_a157_db35d1555ea0 is one of these folders(don't know why it's print the all folder name of this specific folder)

in some other folder tree cases it's works, but in this specific folder tree it's return the same error .

i know that cloud storage don't have real folders and it's part of the name of the object, but you understand what i mean.

is it bug?

Comment: Do you have a job id for the failing job?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, what it looks like is that you have a object file called `gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/apn/reports/appnexus_network_analytics_report/20140901191111_3bab8ec0_092a_43de_a157_db35d1555ea0/` that is not a csv/json file. Some tools may create these dummy files in order to simulate directories. BigQuery requires all objects that match the input glob path to be importable files.

One solution would be to change the glob path to include a narrower set of files. You can pass multiple paths if that makes things easier. For example, you could pass 
`gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/apn/reports/appnexus_network_analytics_report/20140901191111_3bab8ec0_092a_43de_a157_db35d1555ea0/*` 
and 
`gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/apn/reports/appnexus_network_analytics_report/20140901191111_some_other_path/*`

Comment: but all the folders that begin with prefix 'gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/app/reports/app_network_analytics_report/201409011*' contains csv files and not something else

Comment: But it looks like there is an object called `gs://ybbi/bi_landing_zone/files_to_load/apn/reports/appnexus_network_analytics_report/20140901191111_3bab8ec0_092a_43de_a157_db35d1555ea0/` that matches the input pattern but is _not_ a csv file

Comment: Also, if you give a job id it will be _much_ easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: job_id=f2bq_21217a7928eb48e68131ddfeabe6745b_loadfile

Comment: Your path has two *s in it, which isn't supported. I'd try flattening the first * into a list of paths. e.g turn "gs://foo/bar/201409*/data*" into "gs://foo/bar/20140901/data*, gs://foo/bar/20140902/data*, gs://foo/bar/20140903/data*,..."

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand what do you mean "Your path has two s in it, which isn't supported" get you please give me more details

Comment: Two wildcard characters .. I think the stackoverflow formatter may have erased my '*' on the last one

Comment: i'm 100% sure that there aren't Two wildcards, only one at the end of the path like i write. since it's stuck my company loading, i checked it millions times.

Comment: if both of us are right, can it be a reason that some wildcard is enter to my path in your system?

Comment: The job id you gave uses a path that looks like "gs://...pubisher_data/201409*/publisher_data*". There is one wild-card after the date, and another at the end. Do you have another job id from a failed job that only has one '*'?